# My USB mouses aren't working on my windows XP. Do I need to use a PS/2 interface mouse?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, mouse, ps2

So i found this old windows XP, and i plugged in the mouse got it started up, but the cursor on the screen wouldn't move. i tried many mouses and every port on the tower. One mouse glowed red, meaning its plugged it, but it still wouldn't move. The previous owner of the computer said that the mouse she used wasn't a USB.  So, is it a PS/2 Interface? And just in case its helpful, i can't get passed the login screen as the mouse will not move at all. And on an unrelated topic, i cant connect my keyboard either. None of the ports are working for anything.

Comment: WinXP supports a USB mouse, but the BIOS probably doesn't. Try plugging in after XP has finished starting up.

Comment: And check the device manager for yellow marks.

Comment: @JuliePelletier " i can't get passed the login screen as the mouse will not move at all."

Comment: You can surely logon with the keyboard, possibly by using `Tab` and `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP supports USB (heck, Windows 2000 does too) but the USB host controller on the machine may be defective.

Try a PS/2 mouse and keyboard.